# Java acm.program like Clone for C#

Tags: java, c#, winforms, swing

Can anybody guide me about acm.program like libs in C# so that like below Java:
(From https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/tutorial/Introduction.html)

```
import acm.program.*;

        public class Add2Console extends ConsoleProgram {

           public void run() {
              println("This program adds two numbers.");
              int n1 = readInt("Enter n1: ");
              int n2 = readInt("Enter n2: ");
              int total = n1 + n2;
              println("The total is " + total + ".");
           }


    }
```

With Output in a Gui based pseudo console:

[image]

Can we use similar coding in C#?

But I think Because C# is strongly tied to Windows API, so only platform      independent GUI can implement it. Kindly Explain...

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want. For the example you provided you can just use System.Console like this:

```
using System;

namespace Test {
    internal class Program {

        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("This program adds two numbers.");
            var n1 = ReadInt("Enter n1: ");
            var n2 = ReadInt("Enter n2: ");
            var total = n1 + n2;
            Console.WriteLine("The total is {0}.", total);
            Console.Read(); //Just to keep the console window from closing. Press a key to exit.
        }

        private static int ReadInt(string message) {
            Console.Write(message);
            var sInt = Console.ReadLine();
            int ret;
            if (int.TryParse(sInt, out ret)) {
                return ret;
            }
            throw new Exception("You must enter a valid number!");
        }
    }
}
```

And for the gui part c# is not tied to the windows api. c# can be used on linux using mono. A simple example for the gui part of your link could be:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test {
    internal class Program {

        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            MessageBox.Show("This program adds two integers.");

            var n1 = ReadInt("Enter n1: ");
            var n2 = ReadInt("Enter n2: ");
            var total = n1 + n2;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The total is {0}.", total));
        }

        private static int ReadInt(string message) {
            var sInt = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(message);
            int ret;
            if (int.TryParse(sInt, out ret)) {
                return ret;
            }
            throw new Exception("You must enter a valid number!");
        }
    }
}
```

For the last part to work you need to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic since there is no InputBox in c#, it is easy to make one yourself but to keep the code simple i skipped that.

Of course if you want to program gui there are much improvement that can be made here but this is just to show that the code on your link is supported by c#.

If you compile the examples they should run on both linux and mac with the help of mono.

If this is not what you wanted then try to expand the question with some more info.

Comment: What I need is shown in the image... That is to Redirect IO So that Console.ReadLine & Console.WriteLine will use TextBox for IO instead of default cmd window.Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Then just use the InputBox as i did in the last example. string s = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(message); Or do you want to create the window yourself and add a textbox to that? If you want a better and more advanced solution you should look into wpf.